# What's the first digit from left of $(2016)!$

Tags: number-theory, approximation

What's the  first digit from left of $(2016)!$

I tried to use the Stirling formula $$n!\approx \dfrac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2n\pi},$$ but I only could find the number of the digits, I didn't get  the first digit. So how to calculate by  hand that the first digit is $2?$

use WA:[2325849581803\cdots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2016!)

Comment: Use logarithms first.

Comment: First from left or right?

Comment: Hello,  it is  Left

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici,How to use by hand?

Comment: Not by hand, but by logarithms `10^(frac(lngamma(1+2016)/log(10)))` in Pari/GP gives `2.32584958180` as leadings digits.

Answer (score 5):

Apply $\log_{10}$ to $n!\approx \dfrac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2n\pi}$ and get
$$
\log_{10}(n!) \approx n (\log_{10}(n)-\log_{10}(e))+\frac12(\log_{10}(2 \pi)+\log_{10}(n))
$$
Evaluate this for $n=2016$ and get
$$
\log_{10}(2016!) \approx 5788.36656
$$
The exact value is $5788.36658\cdots$ but two decimals are enough:
$$
\log_{10}2 \approx 0.3  < 0.36 < 0.4 < \log_{10}3
$$
and so the first digit is $2$.

This computation can be done with a calculator or in floating point with a computer (which is what I've used), but Stirling's approximation can't be used directly because it overflows to infinity.

We can trust $\log_{10}(2016!) \approx 5788.36$ because the next term in the (alternating) [Stirling series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) for $\ln n!$ is $\dfrac{1}{12n}$, which is $0.00004\cdots$ for $n=2016$. Multiplying by $\log_{10}(e)$, this gives a maximum error of $0.0002\cdots$ for $\log_{10}(2016!)$.

Comment: How do you know that the approximation "$\approx$" in $n!\approx \dfrac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2n\pi}$ is sufficiently precise to ensure that letting $n=2016$ will give the correct first digit of $n!$ ?

Comment: @Alphonse, excellent point! See my edited answer.